# Does Ubuntu Mate 18.04 Have an option for "scroll inactive windows when i hover over them"?

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

i'm totally new to linux and this will be my first ever linux distro, i'm wondering if ubuntu mate has this option because it's a deal breaker for me.. i apologize if the question is dumb i'm just kinda panic-ing.. also if someone can help with this but i'm also liking solus os would you recommend it or no?

Comment: **1:** this site isn't meant for asking about distros that aren't official flavors of Ubuntu. So asking about "solus os" is off-topic here. **2:** You can answer your own question about Ubuntu Mate by testing a Live USB (which you should do for **any** distro you're planning on installing).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible on all current versions of Ubuntu MATE.

Just tested on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS with two MATE Terminals - one active and and one unfocused.
If I scroll (rotate mouse wheel) over unfocused window, it scrolls as expected:

[image: Scroll inactive window on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE]